# Items are not added to Core Data when saving context

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am trying to build a Core Data app and I am using some code based on [this](https://www.objc.io/books/core-data/) book.

To simplify code I have something like this:

```
class City: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged public private(set) var name: String
    @NSManaged public private(set) var population: Int

    public static func insert(context: NSManagedObjectContext, name: String, population: Int) -> City {

        let city: City = context.insertObject()
        city.name = name
        city.population = population

        return city
    }
}


extension NSManagedObjectContext {
    public func insertObject<A: NSManagedObject>() -> A {
        guard let obj = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("City", inManagedObjectContext: self) as? A else {
            fatalError("Wrong object type")
        }

        return obj
    }

    public func saveOrRoleback() -> Bool {

        do {
            try save()
            return true
        } catch {
            rollback()
            return false
        }
    }

    public func performChanges(block: () -> ()) {

        performBlockAndWait {
            block()
            print(self.saveOrRoleback())
        }
    }
}


func addCity() {
    self.context.performChanges {
        City.insert(self.context, name: self.name.text!, amount: Int(self.population.text!))
    }
}
```

When I add a new city, and `save()` is called inside `saveOrRollback()` method on the context, I don't get any error, it will return true.
But there is no data added. I tried to check the sql file and is empty.

Being new to Core Data can someone point me on where to look for issues ? I was expecting to get an error or something when saving, but everything seems to be normal, but the data base is empty all the time.

edit: - added core data setup

```
public func createContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {

    let context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    context.persistentStoreCoordinator = createStoreCoordinator()

    return context
}

private func createStoreCoordinator() -> NSPersistentStoreCoordinator {

    let psc = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: model.managedObjectModel)

    try! psc.addPersistentStoreWithType(model.storeType.type, configuration: nil, URL: model.storeURL, options: nil)

    return psc
}

// Main VC
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let model = CoreDataModel(modelName: modelName, modelBundle: modelBundle!, storeType: .SQLite(DocumentsDirectoryURL()))
    let factory = CoreDataFactory(model: model)

    context = factory.createContext()

    self.todayViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TodayViewController") as! TodayViewController
    self.todayViewController.context = context
}
```

edit 2: - sql debug after adding data

```
-06-18 22:31:15.042 Savings+[1100:39698] CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
2016-06-18 22:31:15.043 Savings+[1100:39698] CoreData: sql: SELECT Z_MAX FROM Z_PRIMARYKEY WHERE Z_ENT = ?
2016-06-18 22:31:15.043 Savings+[1100:39698] CoreData: sql: UPDATE Z_PRIMARYKEY SET Z_MAX = ? WHERE Z_ENT = ? AND Z_MAX = ?
2016-06-18 22:31:15.043 Savings+[1100:39698] CoreData: sql: COMMIT
2016-06-18 22:31:15.045 Savings+[1100:39698] CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
2016-06-18 22:31:15.045 Savings+[1100:39698] CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZTRANSACTION(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZAMOUNT, ZDATE, ZNAME, ZTYPE) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2016-06-18 22:31:15.045 Savings+[1100:39698] CoreData: sql: COMMIT
2016-06-18 22:31:15.046 Savings+[1100:39698] CoreData: sql: pragma page_count
2016-06-18 22:31:15.046 Savings+[1100:39698] CoreData: annotation: sql execution time: 0.0003s
2016-06-18 22:31:15.046 Savings+[1100:39698] CoreData: sql: pragma freelist_count
```

Comment: How/where are you creating your context? Is it a main queue concurrency context attached to a persistent store coordinator?

Comment: How did you inspect the sqlite file?  Have you tried performing a fetch to confirm that the db is empty?

Comment: @SeanCAtkinson: Yes its an MainQueueConcurrencyType and it also attached to a persistent store coordinator. I am creating it in my main view controller and passing it along to the other view controllers.

Comment: @pbasdf: I checked with an sql reader software. But I am trying to fetch them when I first run the app.

Comment: Does your sql reader use the WAL and SHM files, as well as the .sqlite?

Comment: No, I just load the .sqlite file. But still, I am fetching the data when I run the app, and I got nothing (count is 0)

Comment: Can you post the code that sets up the context?

Comment: @SeanCAtkinson: added. Let me know if more code is needed.

Comment: Try enabling SQLDebug to see whether the inserts are happening.

Comment: @pbasdf: I have done this and I edited the question with the output. I am not sure what the output is saying. Is it correct ? Wrong ?

Comment: It shows you are inserting into a table called ZTRANSACTION - which suggests you have a separate Transaction entity which you insert?

Comment: But no sign of an insert into the City entity.

Comment: I just used City as an example here because the code is simplified, but in my real project is called Transaction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115019/discussion-between-pbasdf-and-kobe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments/chat:

1. Remember that the default journal mode for CoreData SQLite databases uses WAL mode, so you need to ensure any sql reader recognises those files.  It's generally easier to use a fetch in your code than to read the sqlite files directly.
2. Try using SQLDebug mode to see what is actually being read/written from/to sqlite.
3. In this case, it transpired that you had a default predicate on your fetch request which excluded all the objects you have saved; removing the predicate shows that the data is there and your save is working correctly.